# Write a query that gives mutual friend names of user DDD and FFF. Also, note that if A is friend of B then B is also friend A

Tags: sql, oracle

Create 2 tables that contains list of friends and users.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  U.username "Mutual Friend"
FROM users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN friends F
  ON U.userid = F.friendid
WHERE f.userid = 6
AND f.friendid IN (SELECT
  friendid
FROM friends
WHERE userid = 4);
```

friends: userid, friendid

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 4
2, 5
2, 7
3, 4
3, 6
4, 7
4, 8
4, 9
5, 6
5, 9
6, 7
7, 8
8, 9
```

users: userid, username

```
1, AAA
2, BBB
3, CCC
4, DDD
5, EEE
6, FFF
7, GGG
8, HHH
9, III
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Mutual Friends
-----------------
CCC
GGG
```

Comment: Do you have a question? This is an order. Try something yourself, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

> EDITED

```
SELECT users.username FROM (
    SELECT
     CASE WHEN userid = 4 THEN friendid else userid END AS "MUTUAL"
    FROM friends
    WHERE (userid = 4 OR friendid = 4) AND
          ( 
          friendid in (SELECT friendid from friends where userid = 6) OR
          friendid in (SELECT userid from friends where friendid = 6) OR
          userid in (SELECT friendid from friends where userid = 6) OR
          userid in (SELECT userid from friends where friendid = 6) 
          )
    ), users WHERE MUTUAL = users.userid
```

Comment: They are asking usernames. not id's

Comment: you are welcome, So please mark it as Resolved :) ( check left the answer )

Comment: It is a pity though that you have to identify the two target users by id, while the question mentioned them by name (DDD and FFF), and that you have to repeat those ids several times (3 x 4, and 4 x 6).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `having` for that:

```
SELECT     u.username "Mutual Friend" 
FROM       users u
INNER JOIN friends f 
        ON u.userid IN (f.userid, f.friendid)
INNER JOIN users v
        ON v.userid IN (f.userid, f.friendid)
       AND v.userid <> u.userid
       AND v.username IN ('DDD', 'FFF')
GROUP BY   u.username
HAVING     count(distinct v.userid) = 2
```